# I messed /dev/tty ownership and permissions

Tags: linux, arch-linux, udev, devices

I was flashing a Flipper Zero Wifi Dev Board and I needed to have /dev/ttyACM0 owned by dialout group...

The thing is now I have tried to revert the stuff, making a chown root:tty /dev/tty*, and chmod a+0666 permissions, and, well... It connects USB on readonly mode.

I can remount Pen Drives easily with a mount command and mode rw, but ironically, I cannot update my Flipper Board now, so I need help... Either making sure everything gets as it should be and making sure any device is connected automatically on rw mode.

I am using archlinux (btw)

I appreciate any help

Comment: Btw, the main idea would be to return all the permissions at /dev/tty* as they were before my mess...

I saw that I should make a udev rule for my dev board. Noted. I wish it was way earlier

Comment: cross-posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1823665/messed-up-with-dev-tty-ownership

Comment: OK, seems like whenever the OS is rebooted, the permissions fall back to normal. However, I still have that very same problem as before: Now, I have to remount any USB device so that they are accessed in rw mode

Answer (score 1):

Almost all modern Linux distributions have udev, which means the `/dev` filesystem is RAM-based: it is rebuilt from scratch at every reboot, so you *cannot* make persistent changes with just `chmod` commands. You would have to set up udev rules or custom start-up scripts for that.

In other words: just reboot and all your changes to `/dev` should be automatically reverted back to standard.

To persistently change device node permissions, you'll need to create *udev rules*. Each distribution can have its own preferred way to handle device permissions. The question tags indicate Arch Linux, so I'd refer you to [ArchWiki's excellent article about udev and permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#Allowing_regular_users_to_use_devices).

For example, Arch's preferred way to grant regular users access to a USB device with particular `vendor_id`:`product_id` numbers would be to create a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/71-device-name.rules` with the following contents:

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="vendor_id", ATTRS{idProduct}=="product_id", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess"

(replacing `vendor_id` and `product_id` with the actual values of course... you can see them in `lsusb` output).

The above udev rule will allow locally logged-in users to access the specified device. If you want the device usable to *all* users, you could omit the `TAG+="uaccess"` part and change the MODE value to `MODE="0666"`. If you want to assign it to the `dialout` group (although this method seems to be deprecated by Arch) you could add `GROUP="dialout"`).

Comment: I did, thank you. The thing is that even /dev came back to standard, didn't do my OS's behaviour. Now I am trying to guess through udev how to make any USB device be connected in rw mode instead of read only.

Comment: If you need write permissions to `/dev/ttyACM0`, then just do a `chmod a+w /dev/ttyACM0` as root.Only storage devices can be mounted: if the firmware update tool uses `/dev/ttyACM0`, no mounting is needed.

Comment: OK, seems like whenever the OS is rebooted, the permissions fall back to normal. However, I still have that very same problem as before: Now, I have to remount any USB device so that they are accessed in rw mode

Comment: Finally got fixed after a yay -Syu was done. Whatever configuration got messed, went back to normal after a software update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently change the permissions of a device associated with a hotplug device (e.g., USB) then you need to make a udev rule.  This answer might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135927

If you want to do this for only one device, you need to include the serial number as shown in that answer.  If you want to do it for an entire class of devices, you can leave out the serial number and include either the device class or the manufacturer or some other shared characteristic.

Comment: Actually, that was why I messed. Instead of the mess I created, I should have modified some udev rules which are made by the Flipper App, changing the group name.

It's already done. Now, as I said in the other comment, I am going to try to understand what was messed and how did it came back to normal. Thank you very much

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using chmod/chown to modify the device files as long as you realize it is temporary.   Actually, this is an excellent way to test things, and if you mess up, you're a reboot away from it being fixed.

Comment: I really appreciate that idea you just gave me. it will be very useful in further elements.